# Quality of a square wave?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, waveform

For an assignment I was asked to evaluate the quality of a square wave I had generated with an op-amp. After spending quite a bit of time searching I have yet to be able to find a definition of the quality of a square wave.

I know of the slew rate and can make an argument for rise time / on time but have not found a formal expression for the quality of a square wave.
Is there a formal definition for the quality of a square wave?

Comment: You could also compute the harmonic distortion (THD)

Comment: I've never heard of the "quality" of a square wave.

Comment: I've never seen a formal definition for one either. Probably the exercise is to see how you approach a less well defined problem. Certainly you can think of imperfections in a square wave and put numbers to them -define your terms  - first, saying, this is the definition of quality I have adopted for this exercise.

Comment: One related area where I HAVE seen a semi-formal definition, is the"k-factor" or impairment in video waveforms, based on the visible effects of square wave quality. See https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OJqjBQAAQBAJ&pg=SA65-PA13&lpg=SA65-PA13&dq=video+impairment+K+factor&source=bl&ots=EJiM36yqJ2&sig=scH6raWOTw2N__XFVpA07qGU90w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifyOGm1rzSAhUnDcAKHc1aDRoQ6AEITjAI#v=onepage&q=video%20impairment%20K%20factor&f=false for some more info.

Comment: The quality of a digital wave can be measured with an [eye-pattern](http://www.edn.com/design/test-and-measurement/4389368/Eye-Diagram-Basics-Reading-and-applying-eye-diagrams).

Answer (score 3):

A Square Wave can be defined by amplitude , rise time, fall time, propagation delay, skew, overshoot, asymmetry, and droop if AC coupled.

When examining asymmetry very accurately at high frequency, it is often difficult to measure due to sensitivity with voltage threshold with slow rise times. But can be done with accurate Time Interval counter or DSO.

### Anecdotal Experience

BEfore the time of DSO's, when I faced this problem, I determined the exact correlation between 2nd harmonic and %asymmetry by lab tests at low frequency, then used a spectrum analyzer to measure the 2nd harmonic content at very high frequencies and got very precise results.  A perfect Square and Triangle Waves are void of even harmonics and if the 2nd harmonic is down 20dB, it might look pretty good on a scope but in fact has poor symmetry which is critical for some applications.

I forget if -23dB was 1% error or more, but something like this. (forgive me it was 30yrs ago)  I used it to measure clock and data symmetry errors, sources of error in magnetic recording, and other applications due to DC offset or bias errors or unequal transition times.

Can you see the asymmetry error?  It's about 35dB down on 2nd harmonic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A square wave should be just that, square. Any deviation from squareness is a lack of quality. Different applications may require quality levels, so there is no one definition of quality. Different methods of generation provoke different defects, so a generation method acceptable for one application might be wanting for another.

An ideal square wave will have vertical edges with no rounding or overshoot, and horizontal top and bottom. Finite bandwidth generation will slope the edges, and potentially create overshoots. Highpass AC coupling will put a slope on top and bottom.

Duty cycle should be 50%, which is easy to do if you use a 2x clock with a divide by 2, but harder if you use a triangle wave and a comparator to generate your square wave.

Pulse n+1 should be the same height as pulse n, so you need a stable power supply. Pulse n+1 should be the same width as pulse n, so you need a stable clock.